# Как на golang использовать функции библиотек, написанных на других языках?

Tags: c#, c++, c, golang, dll

Как на golang использовать функции библиотек, написанных на других языках?
Можете показать какой-нибудь элементарный пример функции на **C; C++;C#** где б функция возвращала значение типа "Hello World", а я б это значение увидел в программе на golang?

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день. Могу ответить только за C. Частью дистрибуции до является CGo. То бишь, все что есть в С можно заимпортировать в Go код. В этом плане есть хорошая статья о том, как же это все сделать https://www.goinggo.net/2013/08/using-c-dynamic-libraries-in-go-programs.html

Из собственного опыта могу сказать, что задача это не простая (пытался написать на CGo расширения для Python). Но если верить документации к Go 1.5 (или новее), то все что собирается в *.o и комплектуется соответственным *.h файлом, можно заимпортировать в Go.

Относительно других ЯП типа C# и С++ не в курсе и не пробовал.

Comment: Ещё наверное стоит отметить, что использование таких библиотек будет негативно сказываться на общей производительности: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272285/why-cgos-performance-is-so-slow-is-there-something-wrong-with-my-testing-code